# Abstract Class with Multiple Levels

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have written the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CI
{
 public:
 virtual void display() =0; 
};


class Inter: public CI
{
 public:
  int parseData (int);
};

Inter::parseData (int data)
{
  cout <<"Parsing the data "<<data;
  return data*100;
}



class Last: public Inter
{
 public:
  void display();
};

void Last::display()
{
  cout <<" Last:: Displaying From Last "<<endl;
}

class USB: public Inter
{
 public:
  void display();
};


void USB::display()
{
  cout <<" USB:: Displaying From Last "<<endl;
}
int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int temp;
  CI *obj = new Last;

  obj->display();
  temp = obj->parseData (100);
  cout <<"Parsed DAta .. "<<temp<<endl;
  delete obj;

  obj = new USB;
  obj->display();
  temp = obj->parseData (200);

}
```

**My Question is:**

Why i am not able to invoke obj->parseData function?. As per my understanding, Hence class 'Last', and 'USB' is derived from  class 'Inter', it should be callable right ?..

Kindly tell me where my understanding is wrong?

Comment: No since obj is of type CI and parseData is not virtual it will look for parseData implementation only in CI class

Comment: If you want a method to be available, you must use a pointer to a level where it is declared. `parseData` was not declared in `CI`.

Answer (score 4):

`obj` must be declared as `Last *`, or at least `Inter *`

```
Inter *obj = new Last;
```

or

```
Last *obj = new Last;
```

If `obj` is just a `CI *`, the compiler can't see the `parseData()` method (your object is instantiated as Last, but immediately implicitly converted to CI and looses the benefit of the method).

I suggest that you look for what the notion of `upcast` means. (See also about `implicit conversion` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) or else)...

Answer (score 1):

The method `parseData()` is not present in `CI`. Even if `parseData()` would be made `virtual` it still would not be found. Remember that virtual functions will only override behavior from a base class, but calling such a function can only happen through pointers to classes that already have such functions. The first class in your hierarchy that has `parseData()` in its interface is `Inter`.

So to resolve it, you could either define `obj` as a `Inter*`, or you could also cast it to a `Inter*` at the call sites of `parseData`. The former is preferred

```
int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int temp;
  Inter *obj = new Last;

  obj->display();
  temp = obj->parseData (100);
  cout <<"Parsed DAta .. "<<temp<<endl;
  delete obj;

  obj = new USB;
  obj->display();
  temp = obj->parseData (200);

}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8a726fd7fc1f1187de7f82480992bdd7-a9c3f5b442fb879fd63f42e442814930).

Comment: `CI` class don't have `parseData()` method, no matter it `virtual` or not. And type casting is not a good way in this situation - it should be avoided when possible, here it's better to use type `Inter` for pointer `obj`.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan thank you, I updated my answer to reflect your point.